# Change Text in a same Layout

Tags: android, layout, text

I'm Making simple app for project

That App contains lot of text so i want,

> "when a button is pressed, text should Change in same layout"

like PowerPoint slide.

I want change text only not scroll.

Now i made my app, have lots of Windows or Layouts.

It is not looking good, too much layout in simple app so please help me .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its easy, init a flag for different slides, show the proper slide on the value associated, then increment this flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this is very easy, I will quickly walk you through the Algorithm:

Set a class level variable called as FLAG initialize it to 1.

Let us assume that FLAG = 1 will represent the first slide. FLAG = 2 the second slide and so on.

Now in your button click you can use a switch case or an if else condition, based on the value of the flag display the relevant text in textview.

Once done, increment the flag, for the next set of sentence(s).

Class level:

```
int FLAG = 1;
```

onCreate:
Initialize your textView:

```
TextView mtv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourid);
```

Set a button click listener:

```
private View.OnClickListener slides = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(FLAG ==1)
                  mtv.setText("First slide");
                else if(FLAG ==2)
                  mtv.setText("Second Slide");

                //and so on...
                FLAG = FLAG+1;//increment flag
        }
    };
```

Comment: Happy coding matey :)